# Custom control width when flex css style used

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I custom control has a text box and a icon next to the text box

```
return (
  <div className="useFlex">
    <TextInput></TextInput>
    <div>
      <Icon></Icon>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Style

```
.useFlex {
  display: flex;
}
```

It works perfectly

But the issue is : when I use this custom control in my page, text box width is not getting expanded and it remains fixed.

```
<Table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td><MyCustomControl> </MyCustomControl></td>
   </tr>
</Table>
```

could you please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
.useFlex
{
   display:flex;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```